# Merge Order Data for invoice

Tags: excel

i have a table with orders from customers, im looking at a way of being able to combine products ordered based on date, supplier and delivery date from a table,the table is very basic and is temp solution.

date, description, item #, qty, supplier & delivery date.

what is the best way to do this and is there any examples. if possible i wish to avoid vba.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with PivotTable in Excel. Select **PivotTable** from the tab Insert, and on the opened dialog box, select your table and the location you want to place the report. After clicking OK, navigate to the Fields pane and choose the fields you wish to include in the report.

Comment: Thanks but is there anyway of doing this without pivot tables ? this is for a user that doesnt really know excel so needs to be easy to use ?