# VBA Combine rows

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking to merge rows with the same data, please see table A the raw data and table B is how im looking for the data to be merged.

i have found some macros on here, but cant seem to get them to merge as they are based on adding numbers, as this is a mixture of text and numbers it of course does not work.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

**Table A**

| DATE | DESCRIPTION | SIZE | ITEM # | QTY | SUPPLIER NAME | DELIVERY DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/08/2023 | Oyster 1 | Box | OY001 | 10 | Supplier 1 | Sunday |
| 02/08/2023 | Oyster 2 | Box | OY002 | 5 | Supplier 1 | Thursday |
| 02/08/2023 | Oyster 2 | Box | OY002 | 11 | Supplier 1 | Thursday |
| 02/08/2023 | Oyster 3 | Box | OY003 | 9 | Supplier 2 | Sunday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 1 | Box | OY001 | 5 | Supplier 1 | Wednesday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 3 | Box | OY003 | 7 | Supplier 2 | Thursday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 2 | Box | OY002 | 9 | Supplier 1 | Sunday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 1 | Box | OY001 | 20 | Supplier 1 | Wednesday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 2 | Box | OY002 | 16 | Supplier 1 | Sunday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 3 | Box | OY003 | 18 | Supplier 2 | Thursday |

**Table B**

| DATE | DESCRIPTION | SIZE | ITEM # | QTY | SUPPLIER NAME | DELIVERY DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/08/2023 | Oyster 1 | Box | OY001 | 10 | Supplier 1 | Sunday |
| 02/08/2023 | Oyster 2 | Box | OY002 | 16 | Supplier 1 | Thursday |
| 02/08/2023 | Oyster 3 | Box | OY003 | 9 | Supplier 2 | Sunday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 1 | Box | OY001 | 25 | Supplier 1 | Wednesday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 3 | Box | OY003 | 25 | Supplier 2 | Thursday |
| 03/08/2023 | Oyster 2 | Box | OY002 | 25 | Supplier 1 | Sunday |

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: If you moved "Quantity" to being the last column, rather than partway through, then this is basically just a PivotTable, no?

Comment: Why did you post [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76827103/merge-order-data-for-invoice) anew? Why did you not simply edit your previous post?

Comment: This is simple in Power Query (available in Excel 2010 and later) if that is an option. You would just Group By all the columns except QTY, and choose to Sum the QTY column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It should be fast, using a dictionary to keep pairs of the two columns, arrays and working mostly in memory. The final processed array is dropped at once, at the end of the code:

```
Sub CombineRows()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrItem, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = sh.Range("B6:L" & lastR).Value
  ReDim arrItem(1 To UBound(arr, 2) - 2) 'redim the array to keep values from column 3 to the last
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'the header is skipped in this phase
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) Then
       For j = 1 To UBound(arrItem): arrItem(j) = arr(i, j + 2): Next j
       dict.Add arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2), arrItem
    Else
        arrItem = dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2))
        arrItem(3) = arrItem(3) + arr(i, 5)
        dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) = arrItem
    End If
  Next i
  
  'redim final array to keep the processed data:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To UBound(arr, 2)) '+ 1 to make space for header:
  'load the header in the final array
   For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2): arrFin(1, j) = arr(1, j): Next j
   
   'load the final array:
   For i = 1 To dict.count
     arrFin(i + 1, 1) = Split(dict.keys()(i - 1), "|")(0)
     arrFin(i + 1, 2) = Split(dict.keys()(i - 1), "|")(1)
     arrItem = dict.Items()(i - 1)
     For j = 1 To UBound(arrItem): arrFin(i + 1, j + 2) = arrItem(j): Next j
   Next i
   
   'drop the final array content at once, and format a little:
   With sh.Range("O6").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .Value = arrFin
    .rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    For i = 7 To 12
        With .Borders(i)
          .LineStyle = xlContinuous: .Weight = xlThin: .ColorIndex = 0
        End With
    Next i
   End With
   
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The above code returns starting from "O6" on the same (`sh`) sheet, but it can be easily changed to return anywhere (a different cell, sheet, workbook). It is enough to change `sh.Range("O6")` with the range where you like the return starting.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Thank you both, the first one seems to have worked is there any difference between the two ?

Comment: @jynxy note: this works providing there is only one supplier for each product on the same day. It fails if on 02/08/23 the 11 oysters 2's are a different supplier ie Supplier 2.

Comment: @jynxy What CDP1802 says its true, but I tried making a piece of code able to process the range as you show it, since you did not set different rules against it. Did you try the code **on the range you show in your question**? If so, what does it return against you need? Does your range to be processed start from the first column ("A:A")?

Comment: I would be starting at B6 there is 13 columns of data (INV-01 | 45143 | Oyster 1 | Small | KS516 | 10 | Pcs | 600 | 0 | 6000 | EUR | Supplier 3 | Wednesday)
i have used the Sub MergeInvoices() which has worked i have not tried the other yet. The reason for this is to then extract the data to go into a PO invoice page, (the last step, that i need to figure out) Thanks for you help it is very much appreciated.

Comment: @jynxy I must show us a reproductible example! This is a general community rule... In terms of what exists, desired design and a piece of code trying to solve the issue. If  no piece of code (where from we could deduce what you try doing), you should state al these aspects, at least, to show how your ranges **exactly** look. I will adapt the code in less than a minute. Only two code lines (the one setting the involved range) must be adapted. And, of course, the place where to return the result. Now, it will be "O6", but as I said, it can be any other (starting) cell... **Adapted**.

Answer (score 3):

Sort then scan up comparing row above, summate then delete if the same.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MergeInvoices()
    Const COL_IN = 1 'A
    Const COLS = 7
    Const COL_OUT = 10 'J
    
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Long

    c = COL_OUT
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        ' clear target columns
        .Cells(1, c).Resize(.Rows.Count, COLS).ClearContents
    
        'Copy
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_IN).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1").Resize(lastrow, COLS).Copy .Cells(1, c)
    
        ' sort copy by date, description, size, supplier, delivery date
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Cells(1, c) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Cells(1, c + 1) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Cells(1, c + 2) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Cells(1, c + 5) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Cells(1, c + 6) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange ws.Cells(1, c).Resize(lastrow, COLS)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        
        ' merge by scanning up the sheet
        For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            ' check row above
            If .Cells(r - 1, c) = .Cells(r, c) And _
              .Cells(r - 1, c + 1) = .Cells(r, c + 1) And _
              .Cells(r - 1, c + 2) = .Cells(r, c + 2) And _
              .Cells(r - 1, c + 5) = .Cells(r, c + 5) And _
              .Cells(r - 1, c + 6) = .Cells(r, c + 6) Then
              ' summate qty
              .Cells(r - 1, c + 4) = .Cells(r - 1, c + 4) + .Cells(r, c + 4)
              ' delete row
              .Cells(r, c).Resize(1, COLS).Delete
              n = n + 1              
            End If
        Next
    
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows merged", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table22"]}[Content],

//set the data type for each column
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"DATE", type date}, {"DESCRIPTION", type text}, {"SIZE", type text}, 
        {"ITEM #", type text}, {"QTY", Int64.Type}, {"SUPPLIER NAME", type text}, 
        {"DELIVERY DATE", type text}}),

//Group by all columns EXCEPT the QTY column
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", 
        {"DATE", "DESCRIPTION", "SIZE", "ITEM #", "SUPPLIER NAME", "DELIVERY DATE"}, 
        
        //Aggregate by SUMming the QTY column
        {{"QTY", each List.Sum([QTY]), type nullable number}}),

//RE-order into original order
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"))
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

***Results from your data***
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Sum Up Unique Rows

```vb
Sub SumUpUniqueRows()

    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    ' Destination
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "I2"
    ' Both
    Const SUM_UP_COLUMN As Long = 5
    Dim UniqueColumns(): UniqueColumns = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
    Const JOIN_DELIMITER As String = "@"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source data range (no headers) and write its values
    ' to a 2D one-based array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        
    Dim srg As Range
    
    With sfCell.CurrentRegion
        Set srg = sfCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - sfCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - sfCell.Column)
    End With

    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Store all upper bounds in variables.
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim uUpper As Long: uUpper = UBound(UniqueColumns)
    
    ' Define a dictionary whose keys will hold the unique joined strings
    ' from each unique column while each corresponding item
    ' will hold the destination row of each joined string.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    ' Declare additional variables to be used in the upcoming loop.
    
    Dim sr As Long, n As Long, c As Long, dr As Long, r As Long
    Dim suValue, rStr As String, IsNoNumber As Boolean
    
    ' Write the 'unique rows and their sums' to the top of the array.
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        ' Join the unique columns' strings.
        For n = 0 To uUpper
            If n = 0 Then
                rStr = CStr(Data(sr, UniqueColumns(0)))
            Else
                rStr = rStr & JOIN_DELIMITER & CStr(Data(sr, UniqueColumns(n)))
            End If
        Next n
        ' Check if the joined string exists in (the keys of) the dictionary.
        If dict.Exists(rStr) Then ' the joined string exists
            suValue = Data(sr, SUM_UP_COLUMN)
            If IsNumeric(suValue) Then
                ' Retrieve the destination row from the dictionary.
                r = dict(rStr)
                ' Sum up.
                Data(r, SUM_UP_COLUMN) = Data(r, SUM_UP_COLUMN) + suValue
            End If
        Else ' the joined string doesn't exist
            ' Write the next (new) destination row to the corresponding item.
            dr = dr + 1
            dict(rStr) = dr ' short for 'dict.Add rStr, dr'
            ' Write the values from the current source row
            ' to the destination row.
            For c = 1 To cCount
                ' Raise a flag i.e. set 'IsNoNumber' to 'True'
                ' if the sum-up column contains no number.
                If c = SUM_UP_COLUMN Then
                    If Not IsNumeric(Data(sr, c)) Then
                        IsNoNumber = True
                    End If
                End If
                ' Check if the flag was raised and write accordingly.
                If IsNoNumber Then 'no number
                    IsNoNumber = False
                    Data(dr, c) = 0
                Else ' is a number
                    Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Reference the destination range and write the values
    ' from the top ('1 to dr') of the array to it.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    
    ' Write.
    drg.Value = Data
    ' Clear below.
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Unique rows summed up.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Columns A&B are sorted. Then, I would do it like this.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If StrComp(Range("A" & lngRow), Range("A" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 _
        And StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        If Range("D" & lngRow) <> "" Then
            Range("E" & lngRow - 1) = Range("E" & lngRow - 1) + Range("E" & lngRow)
        End If
    Rows(lngRow).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: how can i get my score back up? didnt get the negative impact and will be careful in future ?